# How to unescape HTML in Struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, jstl, html-escape

I have saved some basic HTML in a database. This HTML is via `ValueStack` in `Action` class redisplayed as `<s:property value="htmlcodeString"/>` in JSP file.

However, the HTML code is not interpreted, but escaped and displayed as is (eg. <b>BOLD</b> is shown instead of **BOLD**).

I am using Struts2. I found many recommendations on internet to use `<c:out value="${text}" escapeXml="false" />`. But I don't know what it is. How can I make use of it in Struts2?

Comment: Have you looked in the `<s:property>` tag documentation to see if there isn't a similar attribute to turn off HTML/XML escaping? http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/property.html By the way, are you fully aware that when this concerns unsanitized user-controlled input, you're then putting a gaping XSS attack hole open this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The `<s:property>` tag](http://struts.apache.org/docs/property.html) has an `escapeHtml` attribute which is `true` by default.

<sup>(Hopefully for obvious reasons.)</sup>

`<c:out>` is part of the JSTL, and you use it in S2 like in any other web app, with the caveat that it's because of an S2 request wrapper you can use JSP EL to access the value stack.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the question through Google and found adding the `escapeHtml="false"` attribute caused the JSP to stop displaying. What worked instead was simply `escape="false`.

Comment: The `escape` attribute is deprecated years ago.