# Struts2 json return extra \ backward slash

Tags: json, struts2, escaping, backslash, struts2-json-plugin

My Struts2 is currently returning this:

```
[{"pathlocation":"http:\/\/103.231.125.106\/nesos\/cartoon\/151020183506download.jpeg"}]
```

I want this:

```
[{"pathlocation":"http://103.231.125.106/nesos/cartoon/151026121150download.jpeg"}]
```

```xml
<action name="dayofcartoon" method="dayofcartoon" class="foo.bar.AdminInfoAction">
    <result name="json" type="json"> 
        <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
        <param name="root">
         commissioner_info
        </param>            
     </result>
</action>
```

Comment: Struts2 is returning an _escaped_ URL, where forward slashes are _escaped_ by a backslash.  If you tell us more about what you want to do with the URL, maybe we can help you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  how i can remove it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unescape HTML in Struts2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905585/how-to-unescape-html-in-struts2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many JSON encoders escape chars `/` as `\/`. It's not incorrect but is not mandatory. It's related with the `/>` char combination and allow JSON string to be embeded in Javascript code.

If you are using this JSON with Javascript code, you shouldn't be worried about it because Javascript handles it correctly. Both `\/` and `/` are equivalents.

If you should return unescaped response from your Struts2 action then try to force to your JSON encoder to not escape the slash char.

Here you've got a good article talking about this topic: http://andowebsit.es/blog/noteslog.com/post/the-solidus-issue/